# Amazon MWS Reports API results with missing values

Tags: c#, report, amazon-mws

I have been trying my best to make sense of Amazon-MWS' Reports API and have successfully managed to use it to generate an order report with the `_GET_ORDERS_DATA_` enum type as well as the `_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_` type and then save the reports on my local machine. This was all done using C#.

My problem arises from the fact that both of these reports do not seem to have any data in the "quantity" fields which I need to proceed with my project. It produces the product SKUs and Listing IDs, the price of the products and various other fields but not the quantity.

I'm well aware this will probably be seen as a dumb question but I don't know where else to turn so any advice/guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out there was no issue, but the '_GET_ORDERS_DATA_' does not show FBA Fulfilled shipments. I had to use the enum type relating to FBA Fulfilled Shipments to calculatw how many orders had been for each product.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had issues with data, I contact MWS support and they are able to tell me exactly what's going on.  Give that a try: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of fields each of the report type carries from the following link

```
http://bettermws.com/report-types
```

I don't use the reports API for Order processing. I go to the Order API

```
https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=orders&group=orders&version=latest
```

where I can find all the necessary fields related to Order and OrderItems